# Using xticklabel with strange results

Tags: matlab, plot

I have created a scatter plot and am attempting to set the `xticklabel` property of the `set` function but not all of the labels are printing on the plot. As you can see in the attached, there are 11 `x` values. I am including 11 string values in the set function, but only 7 are appearing on `x-axis` of the plot.

What am I doing wrong?

`x` is a 242x1 vector
`haz` is a 242x1 vector
`ls` is a 242x1 vector

```
    scatter(x,haz,30,ls,'filled');
    set(gca,'xticklabel',{'6M';'1Y';'2Y';'3Y';'4Y';'5Y'; ...
       '7Y';'10Y';'15Y';'20Y';'30Y'});
    title(['Implied hazard rates']);
    xlabel('Tenor')
    colormap('Summer');
    colorbar;
    hold on;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your tick labels don't match up with where you *think* the ticks should be. You need to tell the axes to put ticks at each of the x-locations in your plot, probably like this:

```
set(gca, 'XTick', unique(x));
% Now set your tick labels...
```